# UITableView: use object from dictionary as title on detail view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have the following code to make a table from string turned into a dictionary:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSString *testString = @"Sam|26,Hannah|22,Adam|30,Carlie|32";
    testArray = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *s in testArray) {
        testArray2 = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
        [dict setObject:[testArray2 objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[testArray2 objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    if (testArray.count >indexPath.row) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:cell.textLabel.text];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

What I would like is for the selected row title to be set as the title on my detail view.

I tried with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.detailController.title = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailController animated:YES];
}
```

But I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error.

It works fine if I use @"1" as title, it's just something with my dictionary call that's wrong, I assume.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you declare or create detailController...  is self.detailController valid (and not null) in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? does it have a `title` property?

Comment: Yeah everything is valid. If I use @"1" as title everything works, it's just something with my dictionary call that's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `dict` a retained dictionary instead of an autoreleased one.

I.E. declare it maybe like this:

```
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: [testArray count]];
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method. Make sure to release it when `viewDidUnload` is called.

Also, make sure of the number of keys in your `dict` before calling:

```
self.detailController.title = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

So, I would do:

```
if(dict && ([[dict allKeys] count] > [indexPath row])
{
    self.detailController.title = 
        [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
} else {
    self.detailController.title = @"Here's a problem";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement these `UITableView` delegate methods ? All these are needed. Also can you post more detailed StackTrace.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [resultSet count];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 280.0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah everything is valid. If I use @"1" as title everything works, it's just something with my dictionary call that's wrong.